# Need to split a file containing a list of files in to chunks A-G, H-N... using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, text

The text file constans a list of files in alphabetical order.

```
path\afilename1.nnn
path\bafilename1.xxx
path\cafilemane2.sdf
path\ccfilename3.fds
...
```

I need to divide the file to separate files containing list of files starting with letters A to G next file with list of files H to N and so on...

Comment: You can start with something like [this](https://tio.run/##ZcxBDoIwEIXhPaeYhWZ00SbqAeQMbq0xFQZKUgZCSWiCnL1qQaPxLb9/Mm0zUOcMWRtCikmre6N0UVliXdNOMvNsty/03s@YRaw10166vFgwe18eZJG7GZl/EVMQrrVVD6i6o2KEO6xhTOA5N1R9ZkCcqCQPm9V1u4TXML5TZy3KC8KIWjBOf9UIjtV86pRMITwA) and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

I feel like we could somehow make `Group-Object` work for us here, but the switch approach alluded to by Lieven is a really good start.  I would add that `Switch{}` can interrogate a file directly, so something as simple as:

```
$a_g_Files = [Collections.ArrayList]@()
$h_n_Files = [Collections.ArrayList]@()

Switch -RegEx -File 'c:\temp\filelist.txt'
{
    '^path\\[a-g]' { [void]$a_g_Files.Add( $_ ); Break }
    '^path\\[h-n]' { [void]$h_n_Files.Add( $_ ); Break }
}

$a_g_Files | Add-Content "c:\temp\a-gfiles.txt"
$h_n_Files | Add-Content "c:\temp\h-nfiles.txt"
```

This partly depends on if "path" is literal or if it varies from line to line.  But surely even variations can be handled with RegEx.

Comment: If the file is sorted, you could make do with only one Arraylist. It would require more complex logic, but it would save on memory. I would go with the simplest logic to start with but depending on filesize, it might make a valid scenario.

Comment: Agreed. I've never understood why anyone would want to skin a cat, nevertheless, it seems there are multiple ways to do it...  After all, we could output directly to the files in the switch blocks.  Moreover, if we're worried about memory, `Get-Content | ForEach-Object{... | Add-Content ...}` would be much more efficient.  Though I haven't specifically tested the memory efficiency of `Switch -File ...`